# Unable to render the default value on <select> using the defaultValue prop in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My goal is to have a dropdown with all the US state names. If there is a `stateName` in `this.props` (which will be coming from the redux store, in the form of a value like NY, KY or an empty string), I want the dropdown to show it by default. Otherwise I want the dropdown to show 'Select a State' by default and let the user select it. I'm trying to use the `defaultValue` property on the select tag like the following:

```html
<select defaultValue={this.props.stateName}>
  { this.renderStateOptions("someParameter") }
</select>
```

And this is how the `renderStateOptions` function looks like:

```js
const stateNames = [{ name: 'Alabama', abbreviation: 'AL' }, { name: 'Alaska', abbreviation: 'AK' }]

renderStateOptions = () => stateNames.map(stateObj => <option key={stateObj.abbreviation} value={stateObj.name}</option>);
```

The issue here is that even though I have a value in `this.props.stateName` (like NY, KY etc.), the dropdown keeps showing 'Alabama' as the first/default option. Now, in the `renderStateOptions` function, if I add a `selected` prop to the correct state, I get the `Use the defaultValue or value props on <select> instead of setting selected on <option>.` warning, which led me to use `defaultValue` at the first place. I'm not sure what I'm missing in setting up the `defaultValue` prop.

Also, when there won't be any value for the state name (empty string), I want to show 'Select a state' as a disabled/hidden option. I'm doing the following to achieve that:

```html
<select defaultValue={this.props.stateName}>
  <option hidden>Select a state</option>
  { this.renderStateOptions("someParameter") }
</select>
```

This results in overwriting the `Alabama` value I was getting and it just renders the `Select a state` option, which makes sense. What would be a good way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `defaultValue` needs to match the `value` property of the `option` element.

Your code shows that the `defaultValue` is `AL` while the `option` is set-up as `<option value="Alabama">`

So you will have to either set the `defaultValue` as `Alabama` or use `stateObj.abbreviation` for the value.